# Using CodeIgniter cURL to send a push notification via UrbanAirship

Tags: codeigniter, curl, urbanairship.com

I have an urbanairship account set up to send push notifications to my app. This is all working, but now I'm trying to integrate it with my codeigniter admin site so that push notifications are sent by UA and stored to a database in one step. I'm trying to use the cURL library and following the UA API documentation,(http://urbanairship.com/docs/push.html), but each time I get a 404 error. However if I take the cURL lines out, the data is added to the database fine, (so it is receiving the data correctly from the form).

Here's the function in my controller:

> function saveAnnouncement() {
>
> ```
>   $this->load->helper('html');
>   $this->load->library('session');
>   $this->load->helper('json');
>   $this->load->library('curl');
>
>   $new_announcement = $this->input->post('announcement_text');
>
>   if($this->session->userdata('logged_in') != true)
>   {
>       redirect('/admin/login');
>   }
>
>   $this->curl->create('https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/broadcast/');
>   $this->curl->http_login('<application key>', '<master secret>');
>   $announcement_push = array('aps'=>array('alert'=>$new_announcement, 'sound'=>'default'));
>   $announcement_push['encoded_data'] = json_encode($announcement_push);
>   $this->curl->post($announcement_push);
>   $this->curl->execute();
>
>   $this->load->model('Announcements');
>   $this->Announcements->Add($new_announcement);
>   redirect('/admin/announcements');
> ```
>
> }

I'm new to codeigniter, curl and urbanairship, so as you can imagine this is a bit of a nightmare. Will be grateful for any help available!

Thanks!

Comment: I started a codeigniter library for urbanairship here: https://github.com/caioiglesias/Urban-Airship-CodeIgniter-library

Comment: Now, they want money! No more free push!

Answer (score 1):

Have you set your curl config to trust the ssl certificate of the site you are trying to connect? First try with this

```
 curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

and if it works - that's the problem. Then you should setup your curl connection properly adding particular certificate.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. unfortunately it's still giving me the 404 error :S

Answer (score 0):

This code in PHP, `Urbanairship`, `curl` worked for me:

```
define ('URBAN_APP_MASTERKEY', XXXXXX);
define ('URBAN_APIKEY',XXXXX);
define ('URBAN_APP_SECRETKEY',XXXXXX);
define('PUSHURL', 'https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/');

$contents = array();
$contents['badge'] = "1";
$contents['alert'] = "Howdy, doody";
$contents['sound'] = "cat.caf";

$devices = array('device_tokens');

$push = array("aps" => $contents);
$push['device_tokens'] = $devices;

$json = json_encode($push);
$url = PUSHURL;
echo $json; //display the actual content

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, URBAN_APIKEY . ':' . URBAN_APP_MASTERKEY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));

$output = curl_exec($ch);

if($response['http_code'] != 200)
{ 
    echo "Got negative response from server, http code: ". 
    $response['http_code'] . "\n";
}
else
{ 
    echo "Wow, it worked!\n"; 
}

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: will this let you send to individual devices? is $devices an array of phoneIDs?

Comment: @Siriss yes $devices is an array of phone IDs. It will send to individual devices

Comment: Thanks Darshit- How is $devices populated? I am stuck on this one problem.

Comment: @Siriss in my case, its populated from database.. show some code here

Answer (score 0):

Just use normal curl if you are not familiar with Codeigniter !

```
public function pushNotification(){
    // Urban AirShip Doc : http://docs.urbanairship.com/connect/android_push.html

    // create the contents of the android field
    // sample JSON => {"audience": "all", "notification": {"alert": "Hello!"}, "device_types": ["android"]}

    $android = array();
    $android['audience'] = "all";
    $android['notification'] = array('alert'=>'Hello !');
    $android['device_types'] = array("android");

    // convert the dictionary to a json string
    $data = json_encode($android);

    // open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // the url and credentials for posting to urban airship
    $url = 'https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/';
    $username = "YourAPIkey";
    $password = "YourMasterSecretKey";

    // set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Accept: application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . $password);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $arrayResult=json_decode($result);

    // close connection
    $res = curl_close($ch);

    if($arrayResult->ok == 1){
            print "Success";
    } else {
            print "Error";

    }
}
```

Ref : http://blog.jamesbaca.net/?p=385